# Why can an instance of Spring's SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster become huge?

Tags: spring, memory, memory-leaks, heap-dump

I'm looking for culprits taking up memory in a heap dump.

A prime suspect is `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` which seems to have a 128 meg `ConcurrentHashMap` within it. This is possibly the `retrieverCache` within it.

Is it possible to get a memory issue here where for example, events are published but never consumed ?

What happens to an unconsumed event (i.e. one with no listeners) ? Does it live in memory until the death of the JVM ?

Comment: It doesn't cache / hold events it only has references to all the listeners.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the listeners.